# PrimeNG calendar not hiding after selection of value

Tags: primeng, primeng-calendar

In Angular 2, I am using PrimeNG calendar using model driven form with *ngSwitchCase as follows

```
    <div [ngSwitch]="field.controlType">
    ...
    <p-calendar *ngSwitchCase="'date'" [formControlName]="field.key" [id]="field.key" [showIcon]="true" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
    ...
    </div>
```

The calendar comes up well on the UI, but when I select the date, or click outside on the page, it does not go away. 
Only when I click on tab to go away, the calendar is closed.

If I use ngModule, it works fine, but that is not the requirement.

Does anyone have any clue/example on it, please share

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the error that I was using `<div class="section">` somewhere before the primeng calendar. 
Renaming the css *section* class to *appsection* solved this issue.